# Multi Select Listbox is not working

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to select multiple items from the list box and create record for each item in a SQL table. But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).multiselect is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (EVENROL.aspx:334)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)
```

The dropdown list appears but the multiple selection option doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: make sure you have `multiselect ` jquery added if it exist make sure it has been not placed before `jquery.js`

Comment: In Master Page decleared --- <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-cosmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Comment: In the page then ---    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `multiselect` plugin is not being referenced properly. Make sure that it is referenced before your code and that you are implementing it the way you want it to.